# Отследить изменения таблицы MS SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

В Microsoft SQL Server 2015 есть определенная база данных в ней определенная таблица. Нужно отследить какой IP (локальный) произвел изменения в этой таблицы.

Есть такая возможность в MS SQL 2015?

Comment: Можно узнать юзера, который изменял данные, если написать триггер для этой таблицы.

Comment: нет не подходит у меня юзеров под одной учеткой заходит туча

Comment: @SergD29 Сделайте так, чтобы туча не заходила.

Comment: Здесь посмотрите: http://www.sql.ru/forum/589304/kak-uznat-ip-adres-klienta-mssql

Comment: Изменения - это DDL (alter table) или DML (insert/update/delete)?

Answer (score 2):

С версии MS SQL Server 2005 имеется возможность создавать [триггеры DDL](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers) на уровне сервера или базы данных.

С их помощью можно отслеживать различные события, включая интересующие вас. Вот простейший пример позволяющий сохранять информацию о любых изменениях схемы в базах данных сервера:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DDL_Changes]
ON ALL SERVER
FOR DDL_EVENTS
AS 
BEGIN;
   -- таблица в которой логируется информация
   INSERT INTO [changes_log] (dbtime, dbname, username, host, ip, query)
   SELECT
      dbtime    = GETUTCDATE(),
      dbname    = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
      username  = SUSER_SNAME(),
      host      = HOST_NAME(),
      ip        = dmec.client_net_address,
      query     = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
   FROM sys.dm_exec_connections dmec
   WHERE Session_id = @@SPID;
END;
GO

ENABLE TRIGGER [DDL_Changes] ON ALL SERVER
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Если все пользователи работают под одной учётной записью, можно добавить механизм логирования на стороне программы, который будет фиксировать кто, что, где и когда изменил. При этом вовсе не обязательно писать лог в файл. Для этих целей можно создать и специальную таблицу в БД.

Только всё это требует доступа к исходному коду программы. Если это готовое ПО от стороннего разработчика, то Ваша ситуация скорее всего патовая, если, конечно, не удастся выделить каждому пользователю отдельную учётную запись.

Comment: Вся та и проблема что требуется реализовать средствами MS SQL